# Why addView() reset my layout in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I have a thread that call a function in my main activity that should add an image to my layout at a certain position.. When i call my function all works properly but my layout's parameter (margin in my case) resets when i call:

```
myLayout.addView(newImage);
```

That's my function that my thread calls:

```
public void createImageAt(Point location) {
    final ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(90, 90);

    params.leftMargin = location.x;
    params.topMargin = location.y;

    newImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
    newImage.setLayoutParams(params);

    final RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);

    myLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myLayout.addView(newImage);
        }
    });

}
```

My problem is that i have to slide my layout by moving the leftMargin, and when i call the function wrote above the margin jump back to 0 even if it was at -200px

Comment: Is your problem (a) calling `addView()` resets the left margin of `myLayout` back to zero or (b) calling `addView()` ignores the margins set in the LayoutParams of `newImage` ?

Comment: My problem it's point (a). Maybe i said it badly i'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem, that the state does not saves, make `newImage` global variable and reuse it. Just use `myLayout.addView(newImage);` and `myLayout.remove(newImage);`

Comment: Maybe i said that badly, but my problem is not that; The image is correctly displayed at the right position, but the layout reset its margin left when i add it (the image) to my layout